# Deep learning, signal processing and feature engineering

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, signal-processing

1. I have a signals represented in python in dense matrices (the values are y-coordinates from a chart - eg. weather temp etc. in different locations around the world).
2. I'm currently trying to process/recognize these matrices via different kinds of deep neural networks.
3. I'm trying to enhance the important parts of the signals in many different ways as well...I know when we talk about sound / human voice...Log mel, MFCC etc. are useful tool to do such and enhance the important parts and vise-versa...

What are my best options to enhance the most important features (in a similar way) in my dense matrices (in other words to feature engineer the most important features)? I'm of course aware about the fact, that the model can't know what the most important features are and not (without some kind of help / feature engineering - but what more can I do as a human to improve the model). Like set the importance of each feature?

Comment: Might be off-topic for Stack Overflow. You might try asking on the [stats.se] or [datascience.se] stack sites

Comment: The idea with SO sub-sites is good...but the truth is that almost no-one uses them and it is 10 times harder to get an reply there...